# Can i use a 9w led in a 6.5w lamp

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, bulb, light-bulb

My lamp has a label on it that says Max 6.5w 120v 60hz, but I have bulb that I wanted to use that is 9w LED. The bulb that was in there before was also an LED 6.5w.

Would I be able to use a 9w LED bulb in this lamp or would it be too risky?

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's not likely to set the lamp on fire.  *That used to be the concern with people over-lamping *incandescent* fixtures; you'd see a ceiling light with scorched wires and a now-brown "60 watt max" sticker - they had used 100W bulbs there*.

The issue with LEDs is the ability of the LED to cool *itself*.  Unlike incandescents which are deliriously happy inside an oven... LEDs are electronics, like a CPU or video card, and need to keep inside a working operating temperature.

The manufacturer is probably concerned there isn't enough airflow around the bulb to keep a larger LED cool, and that will cause premature failure of the LED.  (like the way you could fry a CPU if the heat sink got loose, though today, they just downclock to a crawl). LED lights lack the sophistication to "down-clock" aka "dim", because that costs money, so they just burn out.